# extend wordpress search query

Tags: search, wordpress

I have a working search query with offset and post_per_page (the user can go through pages)

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'type',
  's'=>$the_str,
  'posts_per_page' => $the_count,
  'offset' =>  ($the_count*$the_c_page )-$the_count
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

It works great.
But now I need to add a meta field to the search function. It should get all post where `s=>$query` OR `meta-field=>$query`
Something like this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'type',
  'posts_per_page' => $the_count,
  'offset' =>  ($the_count*$the_c_page )-$the_count,
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    's'=>$the_str,
    array(
      'key' => 'key',
      'value' => $the_str
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Unfortunately this will only search after the second condition. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to get `WP_Query` to do an `OR` between the main search and the meta search. One alternative is to just [perform two queries](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71582/12496) and merge them but that will mess with your `posts_per_page` which you'll need to handle manually.

Comment: I know. I already foud solutions with two queries. But like you sead, it destroys my page selection. There has to be a better solution for wordpress..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you crack open `query.php` you'll see that it really isn't built with this in mind. It isn't that it isn't a great idea, it's just that each individual query part is concatenated onto the main `WHERE` using an `AND`. So "title contains XYZ" `AND` "whatever the meta query is" `AND` "whatever the tax query is", etc. `Meta` and `Tax` both have sub logic within them that supports `AND` and `OR` but there's no way to perform this between these outer parts.

However, you might be able to do what you're looking for by tapping into one of the filters, possibly `get_meta_sql`. The meta query returns a statement that puts in the `AND` that you want to be an `OR` so you can just look for that and replace it:

```
function change_and_to_or_for_meta( $meta_query, $type, $primary_table, $primary_id_column, $context )
{
   if( 0 === strpos( $meta_query['where'], ' AND' ) )
   {
      $meta_query['where'] = ' OR' . substr( $meta_query['where'], 4 );
   }

   return $meta_query;
}

//Add our filter to replace the AND at the start with OR
add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', 'change_and_to_or_for_meta', 10, 5 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
//Remove our filter so we don't mess other things up
remove_filter( 'get_meta_sql', 'change_and_to_or_for_meta', 10 );
```